# One connection shared between two fragments

Tags: java, android, networking, fragment

I started to write my first mature Android application and I stuck...

I want to implement  tablet view easily to I used android compatibility library v4 and fragments API. Everything was cool until I created network connection and share it beetween two fragments. You know, I have two views...

Let's assume that we have simple chat application and we need to have user list and messages list. I need to implement those both fragments depending from message received from network. So if someone is entering chat I need to update userlist fragment and if someone send new message I need to send it to messages fragment

Could anyone tell me how to do it?
Any ideas how to update both fragments with one connection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you take a look at the chapter about [communication between activities/fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a separate CommunicationManager Class which handles all the sending & receiving - the fragments only display the information you need - all the communication logic is in this one class. Then you will have no problems with your app logic anymore.

Comment: yes , and you can give the CTORs of the fragments the instance of this class if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to use one network connection (saying generally), receive a response and again display it in two different fragments.
There are some patterns you can follow to do that, but here are some suggestions to solve your problem.

- *Try to use the standard Android pattern where you will have:*

  1. A class for **Networking**. (keep it in background or executorthread)
  2. A clsss for **Repository**. (It will be used to fetch the data from the Networking class). When you instantiate the Networking.class in Repository.class use a **Singleton Pattern** so that only one instance of Networking.class is used across the whole app which will let you to use one Networking.class to fetch all the data you need without instantiating Networking.class again.

As @Zakaria suggested, use the Android View model pattern

3. A One **ViewModel** class will be enough to use the Repository.class in it to receive data from the Networking class and share the data (Observe data) in your fragments and show your required data to user.

That's it, it will solve you problem.